# How to checkout a remote forked branch?

Tags: git, github

Hello so I am working on an OS project and am trying to checkout someone else's branch.

Context:

- I have forked the repo and have set it as my origin.
- The original repo is set as my upstream.
- Someone has made a draft pr, to which I want to make adjustments to (and they're aware of it as well).
- I want to checkout his draft pr's branch
- His draft pr is made from his forked repo to the main repo
- I am on master locally

What I've tried:

`git checkout -b [otherDevelopersUsername]:[otherDevelopersBranch] upstream/[otherDevelopersUsername]:[otherDevelopersBranch]`

but I get the following error:
`fatal: 'upstream/[otherDevelopersUsername]:[otherDevelopersBranch]' is not a commit and a branch '[otherDevelopersUsername]:[otherDevelopersBranch]' cannot be created from it`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

edit:

`git remote -vv`
output

origin  [https://github.com/[myUsernam]/[repoName]](https://github.com/%5BmyUsernam%5D/%5BrepoName%5D) (fetch)

origin  [https://github.com/[myUsername]/[repoName]](https://github.com/%5BmyUsername%5D/%5BrepoName%5D) (push)

upstream        [https://github.com/[OrgName]/[repoName]](https://github.com/%5BOrgName%5D/%5BrepoName%5D) (fetch)

upstream        [https://github.com/[OrgName]/[repoName]](https://github.com/%5BOrgName%5D/%5BrepoName%5D) (push)

Comment: I believe -b attempts to create a new branch. Try that command without "-b"

Comment: If the issue persists after you've tried @Joe's suggestion please include the output of `git remote -vv` in your question.

Comment: @tjheslin1 editted @Joe new error: `error: pathspec '[otherDevsUN]:[otherDevsBranch]' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: A *draft* PR isn't in the target GItHub fork yet (I think); only once it's a "real" PR does it has a ref in the target GitHub fork, by which you can retrieve it. That's not a branch name: it's a `refs/pull/<number>/head` ref. As others have said, if you have access to the third repository in which it *is* stored as a branch name, you can use that.

Comment: If you're addicted to shorthand notations, :-) consider using `git checkout -t bobsrepo/branchname` where `bobsrepo` is your remote for Bob's repository where the branch exists. That is, after `git remote add bobsrepo <url>` you would run `git fetch bobsrepo; git checkout -t bobsrepo/branch` and you'd now have a local branch named `branch` whose upstream is set to your `bobsrepo/branch` remote-tracking name.

Comment: Git's names (verbs and nouns and so forth) for these entities are pretty horrible ("remote", "remote-tracking [branch] name", "branch [name]", "upstream", "tracking", etc., all have too many meanings, all contradictory and confusing) but it does eventually make sense. Using the name `upstream` for one of the remotes makes this worse, but it *is* the standard, common second remote name, after `origin`. I like names like `bob` for Bob's repo though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the branch exists on another forked repo, you can obtain it as follows.  Add the forked repo as another remote and checkout from it:

```
git remote add forked https://github.com/something/something.git
git fetch forked
git checkout -b otherDevelopersBranch forked/otherDevelopersBranch
```

`git fetch` fetches any updates and new commits from the remote.
The checkout command will create a local branch that tracks the remote branch `otherDevelopersBranch` on remote `forked`

Comment: I get the same error as the one i posted in the original question.

Comment: Then `otherDevelopersBranch` is not a branch on remote `upstream`.  Make sure the branch is there on the remote, and that you spelled it correctly in the command.

Comment: Also, make sure to do a `git fetch upstream`.  In case your local repo does not have all the updates from the remote.

Comment: Does it matter that it is a pr? This isn't a branch directly on the upstream repo, its a branch on a draft pr that is from another forked repo

Comment: If the branch is not on `upstream` add the forked repo as another remote and checkout from it. `git remote add forked https://github.com/something/something.git` and then `git fetch forked` and `git checkout -b branch forked/branch`

Comment: can you either eddit TTT's answer with your steps or submit a new answer with those steps. That worked and want to give credit. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: @DevAllanPer you can upvote both answers if they helped you. ;) Looks like David provided the exact steps for creating the third remote here, so feel free to give this answer the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question properly, the answer might be obvious.

You have two remotes:

1. `origin` which is *your* fork of the repo.
2. `upstream` which is the original repo.

And someone else made a PR, about which you state:

> His draft pr is made from **his forked repo** to the main repo

The words "his forked repo" implies he has *his own fork* where his branch resides. In that case, you need a third remote pointing to his forked repo, in order to pull from it.

Comment: You may be right, so from my understanding of your answer, there is no way to get that pr's branch from the original repo?

Comment: If the branch is not on the original repo, then no, you cannot get it from the original repo.   You can, however, get it from the repo that has that branch. Add that repo with the `git remote add` command.